# BLE dongle API interfacing in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, bluetooth-lowenergy, dongle

My aim is to create an excel VBA utility which interfaces with the BLE dongle connected to a USB Comport.

I am using [BLED112](https://www.silabs.com/wireless/bluetooth/bluegiga-low-energy-legacy-modules/device.bled112) dongle which uses the [BGAPI](https://www.silabs.com/content/usergenerated/asi/cloud/attachments/siliconlabs/en/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base/jcr:content/content/primary/blog/_reference_bgapib-Alq6/BGAPI_BGLib_Overview_Presentation_v10.pdf).

I have been able to successfully implement the sample C example at [BLED112 Example](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base.entry.html/2017/03/05/spp_client_exampleu-uKCx) on my setup.

I need to interface the BLED112 Example with my Excel VBA such that data from BLED112 Example can be sent to Excel VBA, and vice-versa. For example, list of nearby Bluetooth devices can be seen in column in Excel etc.

I tried to create a dll from the BLED112 Example and add it to my Excel VBA code. However, i was unable to call any functions in the dll from my Excel VBA code.

My questions are:

1. How can I access the BLED112 Example code from my Excel VBA project?
2. The BLED112 Example prints data into the console. How can i get the data into Excel VBA?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: As far as I remember VBA is able to call .NET assemblies. So you can try to use Bluetooth Framework .NET Edition (it supports BLED112)

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks a lot for the suggestion. However, I am not very well with C#. Plus the .NET Edition is trial version, not fit for long term goals.

Comment: The other possible way is to develop DLL and call the DLL from VBA.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I am unable to do that. That's what i need help with.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know other free solution. You can found some free c# libs (that provides very basic features) (for example: https://github.com/ahouben/BleDriver.NET) but you have to do some job any way.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks a lot for putting some efforts for me. I will definitely do the necessary changes. However i need something that does not deal with C# as i won't be able to modify that, since i don't know C# very well.

Comment: Then (as I wrote) BGAPI + DLL.

Comment: I tried this, however as mentioned in my question "I tried to create a dll from the BLED112 Example and add it to my Excel VBA code. However, i was unable to call any functions in the dll from my Excel VBA code." Any help/suggestion with this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/how-to-access-dlls-in-excel

Comment: I already tried this, generating dll from the code and interesting with the vba. However, i couldn't call any functions from dll. I think the execution of C code is such that it is not supporting dll. Still stuck.

Comment: And what does not work exactly? DLL not found? Function not found? Other error?

Comment: And, of course, you can always create COM object that can be called from VBA without any problem (prffered way).